# NSMutableSet with custom isEqual: and hash callbacks

Tags: ios, parse-platform, core-foundation, foundation, nsmutableset

I am trying to create a custom `NSMutableSet` that doesn't use the standard `isEqual:` and `hash` selectors on objects.

Typically I want to use this with Parse. I have a `NSMutableSet` containing `PFObject` subclass instances, and I consider them equal if they have the same `objectId`.
I know I could override `isEqual:` and `hash` in my `PFObject` subclass, but I don't want that functionality on all my objects. Besides, Parse uses these methods internally, so I don't want to mess up with them.

Here is what I have come up so far :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSMutableSet (Additions)

+ (NSMutableSet *)setWithParseObjectIdIsEqualCallback;

@end
```

```
#import "NSMutableSet+Additions.h"

@implementation NSMutableSet (Additions)

static Boolean ParseObjectIdIsEqualCallback(const void *value1, const void *value2)
{
    PFObject *obj1 = (__bridge id)value1;
    PFObject *obj2 = (__bridge id)value2;
    NSCParameterAssert([obj1 isKindOfClass:PFObject.class]);
    NSCParameterAssert([obj2 isKindOfClass:PFObject.class]);
    NSCParameterAssert([obj1 isMemberOfClass:obj2.class]);

    return [obj1.objectId isEqualToString:obj2.objectId];
}

static CFHashCode ParseObjectIdHashCallback(const void *value)
{
    PFObject *object = (__bridge id)value;
    NSCParameterAssert([object isKindOfClass:PFObject.class]);

    return object.objectId.hash;
}

+ (NSMutableSet *)setWithParseObjectIdIsEqualCallback
{
    CFSetCallBacks callbacks = kCFTypeSetCallBacks;
    callbacks.equal = ParseObjectIdIsEqualCallback;
    callbacks.hash  = ParseObjectIdHashCallback;
    CFMutableSetRef set = CFSetCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &callbacks);
    return CFBridgingRelease(set);
}

@end
```

I don't really know if it will work or if it is safe to use, and I'm quite unfamiliar with Core Foundation objects and functions like `CFBridgingRelease()`.

Comment: How about creating an `NSObject` subclass that uses an NSMutableSet. That way you can forward most of the functions onto the set and just do your own equals function and stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is needlessly complicated: you could provide your own `isEqual:` and `hash` implementations in a *wrapper* class, and wrap your `PFObject`s in it before placing in the `NSMutableSet`:

```
@interface PFObjectWrap {
    PFObject *_obj;
}
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)other;
-(NSUInteger)hash;
+(PFObject*)wrapped;
-(id)initWithPFObject:(PFObject*)obj;
+(PFObjectWrap)wrap:(PFObject*)obj;
@end

@implementation PFObjectWrap
-(id)initWithPFObject:(PFObject*)obj {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _obj = obj;
    }
    return self;
}
+(PFObjectWrap)wrap:(PFObject*)obj {
    return [[PFObjectWrap alloc] initWithPFObject:obj];
}
+(PFObject*)wrapped {
    return _obj;
}
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)other {
   // Put your custom implementation here
}
-(NSUInteger)hash {
   // Put your custom implementation here
}
@end
```

Now you can wrap your objects into `PFObjectWrap` before adding to `NSMutableSet`:

```
NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet set];
[set addObject:[PFObjectWrap wrap:myObject1]];
[set addObject:[PFObjectWrap wrap:myObject2]];
```

Of course you also need to wrap before searching `NSMutableSet`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't thought of that. Although I don't think it is really simpler, it looks a lot safer, at least until I have confirmation that the code that I wrote is good.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. All bridge casts use the right ownership semantics. I don't see any obvious errors.

I think this solution is better than using a wrapper object.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler, I made an method on my Parse subclass that lets me treat an `NSArray` as an `NSSet`.

```
- (BOOL)isContainedInArray:(NSArray *)array {
    for (Tag *tag in array) {
        if ([self.name isEqualToString:tag.name]) {
            return YES;
        }
    } return  NO;
}
```

In the view controller where I use it, run this method to determine whether or not to add it to my `NSArray`. I originally overwrote `isEqual` and `hash` but as you mention, it creates conflicts with Parse's internal logic.